# What is use case of thenAcceptAsync in lettuce

Tags: lettuce

What is use case of `thenAcceptAsync`? There is an explanation on https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#asynchronous-api, but I do not get it.

I thought `thenAccept` is already handling the event async and it is not blocking the main thread. In what use cases do I need `thenAcceptAsync`? It'd be great if there is an example.

Answer (score 0):

`thenAccept` is executed in the event loop of netty, if you are calling a long/blocking operation using `thenAccept` you are going to block the event loop.
So in this case you can run a long running/blocking part of your code in a separate executor to keep event loop free.